# Text in "People or Group" field doesn't show when printed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, printing

We have a list in SharePoint 2013 with a columns using "People or Group", no multiple selections is allowed. When we print the list, the text is replaced with the url to the list item. Can anyone explain this behavior and describe how to get the actual text printed instead (name of person etc).

Comment: Is it already replaced in the Print Preview dialog?

Comment: No, it's not. It looks OK in the Print Preview.

Comment: What if you print it to PDF (or some other file) instead of physical printer?

Comment: The issue remains. We have tried pdf and OneNote, but it doesn't help.

Comment: What if you modify the Field properties and make it render, e.g., user email address instead of whatever it is rendering now?

Comment: It seems like if I go to the list itself and print it, the result is OK. However, if we add the list as a web part on a web page and print the page, we get this issue.